# Parse Date and Time in specific format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting timestamp string in the following format -

```
2015-02-01T12:11:06Z
```

I need to convert it into DateTime object. I tried the following code for this -

```
timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(attr.Value,"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss",null);
```

But it's throwing Exception.

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>
> at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
>
> at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)

I know that my format is wrong. Any way to make it work?

**Update**
J. Steen's method worked for me and he was the first one to comment, but Soner Gönül provided much better explanation and a better way, so I am accepting Soner Gönül's answer as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers) and as J. Steen agreed with this. Thanks to both of you. I am upvoting all the correct answers anyways. :-)

Comment: You shouldn't need a format string at all. Just DateTime.Parse, as your datetime string is already in a valid date time format.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to have included that final Z in your format.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("2015-02-01T12:11:06Z")` <- Works wonderfully.

Comment: Thanks @J.Steen I thought it was not a valid DateTime, so tried custom format..

Comment: I cant see an am/pm part of the time here so you should change the "hh" to "HH" (24 hour format)

Comment: @noob I sincerely think you should accept Soner's answer, considering it's far more complete and uses a more secure way of parsing dates.

Comment: @J.Steen Thanks for clearing my dilemma. I'll accept his answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget the `Z` part at the end and change `hh` to `HH`;

```
string s = "2015-02-01T12:11:06Z";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt); // 01/02/2015 14:11:06
}
```

Since there is no custom date and time format as `Z`, parsing methods see it as a character literal. But in such a case, your hour part will be different with `OffSet` since this operation creates your [`DateTimeKind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as `Local`. Since my current offset is `+02:00` right now, it will generate `14:11:06`, not `12:11:06`

```
string s = "2015-02-01T12:11:06";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt); // 01/02/2015 12:11:06
}
```

Comment: You use Linqpad. I can tell. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen Yeap :) Changed it to `Console.WriteLine` the same time when you write your comment.

Comment: The only answer so far to specify CultureInfo.InvariantCulture: without this it may fail if the current culture uses a TimeSeparator other than ":"

Comment: @Joe Which, however unlikely, can definitely happen, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the format you supplied doesn't match the `Z` timezone in the end. You should add a suffix to match that. For example: `"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ"`. By the way, FYI, **Z** stands for **Zulu** and means the same as **UTC**.

But the simplest fit-for-all solution is `DateTime.Parse(attr.Value)`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a format string at all. Just `DateTime.Parse`, as your datetime string is already in a valid (and highly standardised) datetime format.

```
timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2015-02-01T12:11:06Z",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None);
```

works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

In the time format the letter Z, stands for UTC time is also known as 'Zulu' time.

This means the parser will treat the time string as UTC time and when parsing it will convert time to your local time zone.

You could modify your code to achieve it as follows,

use timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(attr.Value,"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss**Z**",null);

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("2015-02-01T12:11:06Z")
```